# evaluate multiple functions of one dataframe and cbind them in R

Tags: r, lapply

I'm evaluating 4 functions over the same dataframe that return one vector each. I would like to cbind the results into one dataframe. This is what I tried:

```
df <- cbind(1:10,11:20)
myf1 <- function (data) {data[,1]*data[,2]}
myf2 <- function (data) {data[,1]^2}
myf3 <- function (data) {log(data[,2])}
myf4 <- function (data) {scale(data[,1])}

myfunc <- c('myf1','myf2','myf3','myf4')

mydf <- lapply(myfunc,function(x) eval(paste(x,'(df)',sep='')))

do.call(cbind, mydf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> library(fortunes)
> fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

The same is true for `eval`.

Put your functions in a list, then call `lapply` on it.

```
> myfunclist <- lapply(myfunc, get)
> mydf <- lapply(myfunclist, function(f) f(df))
> do.call(cbind, mydf)
```

Comment: or simply `mydf = lapply(myfunc, do.call, list(df))`

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich one variant of this might be to specify directly in the vector `myfunc <- c('myf1(df)','myf2(df)','myf3(df2)','myf4(df2)')` is there a way of evaluating this in case that I have several dataframes? Let's say `df2 <- cbind(21:30,31:40)`

Comment: @eccehomo you'd be better off using `mapply` in that case, with a list of functions, and a list of data.frames. `eval(parse(text=...))` is **not** something you should need to do in R.